# How can I import .sql file in my MYSQL DB using spring boot?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, import, spring-data-jpa

I need to develop a service which will able to execute **uploaded** .sql file on the MySQL DB. Means, I will upload a .sql file from front-end and hit my URL which will then excecute that .sql file on my DB and procced accordingly.

I searched for solutions and found some solutions as well and I didn't get the exact view for the same. I am using JPA query for implementing the said process.

**Repository**

```
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "IMPORT TABLE FROM ?1")
    void inserMarketPriceTable(MultipartFile file);
```

Please help me out through this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest to keep uploaded files on some server location and execute shell script that will run files.

Comment: @MandarDharurkar Thanks for the reply. I found this solution one of the most secured way.

Answer (score 0):

In my company we use flyway to do something similar. We upload the db scripts in a specific folder and then use a bash script/jenkins task to execute the changes. If you're familiar with the Laravel Migration tool, it kind of works the same way. The CLI doesn't require much installation or configuartion.

[Flyway link](https://flywaydb.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I choose other format for my thing but I found your solution  totally correct